# how to print a certain number of bytes(characters) pointed by a pointer

Tags: c

I have a pointer which point to a memory of 20 bytes, and then copy something to the memory

```
u_char* pkt=malloc(20);
memcpy(pkt, somecontent, 20);
```

I want to examine the 20 bytes starting from pkt
so I want to print all the bytes with a format like `0xa6`
how to do this in language C

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is sufficient,

```
int i=0;
u_char  * ptr=pkt;
for (; i<20; i++)
  printf("%x ", ptr++);
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`printf`](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html#printf) :

```
int i=0;
for (; i<20; i++)
  printf("0x%.2x ", pkt[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: That is exactly what this man needed, but I'd also suggest him reading printf man pages, for example here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf